# Error al guardar datos en mi BD

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes si me pueden ayudar con esto al momento de guardar datos en mi tabala de BD no me guarda nada, ya imprimo los valores y si me los envia pero al hacer una consulta me da error.

**este es la parte de mi codigo:**

```
echo $consul2="select * from resul_biometria where numero_factura='".$fac."' and id_cliente='".$clien."' and fecha='".$fecha_fac."'";
    $query2=mysqli_query($con,$consul2);
    echo $query2;
    $count2=mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    echo $count2;
if ($count2<=0)
    {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO resul_biometria(numero_factura,id_cliente,id_medico,fecha,eritrocitos,hemoglobina,hematocrito,conmedhemo,volglomed,plaquetas,leucocito,monocito,monocito2,linfocito,linfocito2,eosinofilo,eosinofilo2,basofilo,basofilo2,neusegm,neusegm2,neubanda,neubanda2,estatus)
        VALUES('".$fac."','".$clien."','".$medic."','".$fecha_fac."','".$eri."','".$hemo."','".$hema."','".$cmh."','".$vgm."','".$placas."','".$leu."','".$mono."','".$mono2."','".$linfo."','".$linfo2."','".$eos."','".$eos2."','".$baso."','".$baso2."','".$neuseg."','".$neuseg2."','".$neuban."','".$neuban2."'1)";
        $query_new_insert2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        if (@$query_new_insert2) {
            echo '<script>
            jQuery(function(){
              swal("Exito", "Registro Guardado!!", "success");
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
              location.href="javascript: history.go(-1)";
            }
            ,1500);
           </script>';
        } else {
             echo '<script>
             Query(function(){
              swal("Upss", "Error", "error");
              });
        setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.href="javascript: history.go(-1)";}
        ,1500);
       </script>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql3 = "update resul_biometria set eritrocitos='".$eri."',hemoglobina='".$hemo."',hematocrito='".$hema."',conmedhemo='".$cmh."',volglomed='". $vgm."',plaquetas='".$placas."',leucocito='".$leu."',monocito='".$mono."',linfocito='".$linfo."',eosinofilo='".$eos."',basofilo='".$baso."',neusegm='".$neuseg."',neubanda='".$neuban."',monocito2='".$mono2."',linfocito2='".$linfo2."',eosinofilo2='".$eos2."',basofilo2='".$baso2."',neusegm2='".$neuseg2."',neubanda2='".$neuban2."' where numero_factura='".$fac."' and id_cliente='".$clien."' and id_medico='".$medic."' and fecha='".$fecha_fac."'";
       $query_new_update2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);

       if ( @$query_new_update2) {
            echo '<script>
            jQuery(function(){
            swal("Exito",
            "Registro Guardado!!",
            "success");});
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href="javascript: history.go(-1)"
            }
            ,1500);
           </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>
        jQuery(function(){
        swal("Upss",
        "Error",
        "error");});
        setTimeout(function(){
           window.location.href="javascript: history.go(-1)";}
        ,1500);
       </script>';
    }
}
```

**Esto es lo que me dice:**

select * from resul_biometria where numero_factura='1' and id_cliente='20' and fecha='11/10/2020'
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\LAB\guardar_biometria.php on line 37

Comment: No puedes hacer esto: `echo $query2;` porque `$query2` es un objeto de tipo `mysqli_result` no una cadena (eso es lo que te dice el error). Luego, no creo que tu consulta encuentre nada si le pasas la fecha así: `11/10/2020` y esa columna es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`, pues en las BD  las fechas se guardan en formato  (año, mes, día), algo así: `2020/10/11` si hablamos del 11 de octubre de 2020

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en un dilema entre si tú codificas mal o de plano no entiendo tú código.

Te dejo este enlace donde parecen tener tu mismo problema:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722375/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in